# Angular2+ two-way binding to cause sibling to update on initialisation

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-changedetection

I have 3 component structure. Parent component has 2 arrays, allItems and pagedItems. Pager component has input value of items and two-way binding of pagedItems. Table component has input value of paged items.

Example of the components

```
export class Table {

    @Input()
    pagedItems: any[] = [];
    constructor() { }
}

export class Pager {
    items: any[];

    @Input()
    set items(value: any) {
        this._items = value;
        this.setPage(this.currentPage);
    }

    get items() {
        return this._items;
    }

    _pagedItems: any[];

    @Input()
    get pagedItems() {
        return this._pagedItems;
    }

    @Output() pagedItemsChange = new EventEmitter();

    set pagedItems(value) {
        this._pagedItems = value;
        this.pagedItemsChange.emit(this._pagedItems);
    }

    setPage(page: number) {

        this.pager = this.pagerService.getPager(this.items.length, page, parseInt(this._pageSize));
        this.pagedItems = this.items.slice(this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.endIndex + 1);

    }
}

export class Parent {

    allItems: any[] = [];
    pagedItems: any[] = [];

    ngOnInit() { this.getData(); }
    getData() {
        ajaxcall.then(data => {
            this.allItems = data;
        })
    }
}
```

And here is the example of the HTML structure:

```
<table class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 main-tbl pl-0 pr-0"
                                 [pagedItems]="pagedItems"
                                ></tbl-img-procurer-browser>

        <pager class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 main-tbl pl-0 pr-0"
               [items]="allItems" [(pagedItems)]="pagedItems"
         ></pager>
```

When I open the parent component, it invokes the getData() method. This gets data from server and puts it into the allItems array. Now pager gets the array and pages it. And populates the pagedItems array. Now what should happen is that the table component gets the paged items and renders them. But what actually happens is that the table never gets the data. Now if i change the pages on the pager, the table suddenly gets the data and starts showing it. Why doesen't it get the data during the initialization?

EDIT:

At first i thought this was unnessesary piece of info, but with the answer Mickers gave, i think this is nessesary.

I have one additional component that handles the search form for the table. The this components onInit creates an event that the parent listens to and uses data from the event to do the getData() ajax call. I dont know if i can use resolve guard here.

```
export class filter{

@Output("onSubmit") onSearch: EventEmitter<SearchInput> = new EventEmitter<SearchInput>();

ngOnInit(){
    this.onSubmit();
    this.onSubmit();
  }

getSearchInput(){
    let searchInput: SearchInput = new SearchInput(
      //collects data from search form.
    );

    return searchInput;
  }

onSubmit() {
    this.onSearch.emit(this.getSearchInput());
  }

}
```

So the structure is actually:

```
 <filter (onSubmit)="getData($event)"></filter>
 <table class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 main-tbl pl-0 pr-0"
                                     [pagedItems]="pagedItems"
                                    ></tbl-img-procurer-browser>

            <pager class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 main-tbl pl-0 pr-0"
                   [items]="allItems" [(pagedItems)]="pagedItems"
             ></pager>
```

Comment: You're not using a component so that doesn't help my suggestion which would be to use the ngOnInit lifecycle hook to make sure your html has rendered. Is there any chance you could use a Resolver Guard? Again this would require a component but a resolver will fire and load your data before the component loads.

Comment: @Mickers i probably could. Can you give an example on how you woud use it here?

Answer (score 0):

I can provide an example on how to implement this.

First you need to update your router (you must be using a router for this fix to work):

```
const HOME_ROUTE: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', // replace this with your route and component name
    component: HomeComponent,
    resolve: [HomeResolver] // this is where you implement the guard
  }
];

export default HOME_ROUTE;
```

Here's an example of what the guard would look like:

```
@Injectable()
export class HomeResolver implements Resolve<string> {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<string> {
    console.log('home resolver fired');
    return of('true');
  }
}
```

Update your component to pull the data:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(({ str}) => {
        this.message= str;
    });
}
```

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Please refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@dazcyril/resolving-data-in-angular-2-4-and-5-refactoring-components-and-moving-to-ngrx-store-15e15d8be3dd) for more information

Comment: But would this work if one of the child components fires the getData event in its ngOnInit hook? As i understand, this would work, if the get data gets fired from the parent. If you look at the question, i edited it, added in more details. I dont know if the guard can work in that case.

Comment: Once the page has loaded the resolver has done it's job. If additional calls during the lifecycle of the child components then they should be handled in by the parent. The parent can update the children as needed. Angular should be smart enough to only re-render child components that have changes.

Comment: This is part of the container-component style where the parent is just a container that makes server calls and updates the components or children. There's little to no logic or HTML in the container component. It simply handles the data and passes it down.

Comment: So there is no good way to make so that the child component starts the update cycle from the beginning ? Currently in the filter component i invoke the onSubmit twice. 1 time it get everything but does not update the entirety of DOM, the second time it also updates the DOM. This is bad because it does the ajax calls twice, but atleast it is giving results.